# How to target Elements through Directives which are rendered by Angular Material using class selector

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am testing out a simple use case, wherein i have created a directive(selector being a class name), while everything runs as expected when i try to target simple classes, the directive doesn't get initialised incase of Angular Material elements, for the test case i have used a simple MatMenu, while it is open it renders a div with the class `cdk-overlay-container` which is my target and source of the problem that is the directive doesn't get called.

Any help would be great,

[Link to Code: StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hoverdirective-nodv2q?file=src/app/EventhoverDirective.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's `directive` with a `class` selector can only target static element in the DOM. [It can't target class names that are dynamically inserted into the DOM](https://medium.com/swlh/anatomy-of-angular-attribute-directive-selector-a1d83a73242#:%7E:text=One%20caveat%20with%20the%20class%20selector%20is%20that%20you%20cannot%20target%20class%20names%20that%20are%20dynamically%20inserted%20into%20the%20DOM%20using%20an%20expression%20binding%20either%20via%20a%20class%20binding%20or%20NgClass%20attribute%20directive.).

In your case, `cdk-overlay-container` is dynamically inserted into the DOM when you click on the menu. Hence, a simple static class worked.

Comment: Is there a work around for it ?

Comment: @TheViralGriffin It depends on your use case. In your sample code, you only want to highlight on mouse-enter. You can achieve the same behavior with just plain CSS. `CLASS:hover` should be sufficient.

Comment: well my actual use case is to add a class to the dynamically rendered element, currently trying with role attribute and even that is failing.

Comment: @TheViralGriffin Please create a new question, and post a link here. I will try to answer when I have a chance.

Comment: Link to new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74065530/how-to-add-a-class-to-dynamically-rendered-angular-material-components